# How to prevent the currently open modal from closing when another modal is opened in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building pages using `vue.js` and `bootstrap-vue`.
A problem that can not be solved for several hours is that the modal is closed when another modal is opened while the modal is opened.
Is there a way to open a new modal while maintaining the existing modal?

Comment: Hi @kisstest. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not figure out. so i create custom modal component...